# Moving a sudo command from bash_profile

Tags: macos, .bash-profile

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan. Because of Eclipse Che, I need these lines on `.bash_profile`

```
export DOCKER_VM_IP=$(docker run --rm --net host alpine sh -c "ip a show eth0" | grep 'inet ' | cut -d/ -f1 | awk '{ print $2}')
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias $DOCKER_VM_IP
```

It's annoying to write the password anytime I open a new terminal window, because of `sudo` command. What could be the better approach to fix this?

- One idea is to move those lines to a different place, but where?
- Any other idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I use Linux, so I can't test the following, but you could try using the SETUID bit on `ifconfig`, as in `sudo chmod -v +04000 $(which ifconfig)`. If OSX allows it, this should give root privileges whenever `ifconfig` is run. If this reduces security too much, you could copy `ifconfig` to a local, private directory, add the SETUID to the copy and use this in your `bash` start-up file: obviously, you need to do this as `root`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SUID bit you could allow [passwordless sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password#159009) for this one command (and this specific user) in your `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/ifconfig`:

```
youruser yourhost = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig lo0 alias *
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT: If you find a security issue with this procedure, or there is a better and secure way to do it, please, comment. I would appreciate it.**

Following the advice from @AFH's comment, I did this and it worked:

First, I copied `ifconfig` to a new folder.

```
$ cd /Users/username
$ mkdir sbin
$ sudo chown username:staff ./sbin
$ sudo chmod 700 ./sbin
$ cd sbin
$ cp /sbin/ifconfig .
```

After that, I applied the SETUID

```
$ sudo chown root:wheel ./ifconfig
$ sudo chmod +s ./ifconfig
```

Finally, I modified `.bash_profile`, removing the `sudo` command

```
export DOCKER_VM_IP=$(docker run --rm --net host alpine sh -c "ip a show eth0" | grep 'inet ' | cut -d/ -f1 | awk '{ print $2}')
~/sbin/ifconfig lo0 alias $DOCKER_VM_IP
```